# Menu com layout customizado

Tags: android, android-layout, menu

Preciso criar menu customizada para que fique dessa forma:
[image: layout do menu]

então criei um .xml em res/layout/layout_menuitem.xml para servir como menu do meu app.

`<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_minha_conta"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/minha_conta"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_meus_pedidos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/meus_pedidos"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_notificacoes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/notificacoes"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_fale_conosco"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/fale_conosco"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_politica"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/politica"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_sobre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sobre"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_sair"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sair"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/apptheme_color"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook_icon_small"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/email_icon_small"/>
</LinearLayout>`

Porém não consigo fazer o mesmo layout para menu, e também não consigo o **layout_menuitem** como menu da aplicação.

Comment: O seu arquivo de menu deve ficar na pasta **res/menu/**, além disso, coloque os **TextViews** dentro de um layout ( ex.: LinearLayout), não os deixem "soltos".

Comment: Eu acho que deveria usar essas funções de acordo com as recomendações de melhores práticas do Android. Ou seja, o botão de menu no canto esquerdo.